# Regex capture text between two dynamic texts

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

First of all I would like to admit that I am not good at regex.

I have this string:

```
[my_section title="Foo" the_id="123"][my_text]my example text[/my_text][/my_section]
```

What is possible way to capture everything except `[my_section title="Foo" the_id="123"]` and `[/my_section]` or simply saying any text between these two?

My knowledge on this is not working at all.

I cannot use literal `[my_section title="Foo" the_id="123"]` because the params after `[my_section` is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_match('~\[my_section[^\]]*\](.+?)\[/my_section\]~', $string, $match);
```

The string you want is in `$match[1]`

If you want to match newlines, add the `s` modifier:

```
preg_match('~\[my_section[^\]]*\](.+?)\[/my_section\]~s', $string, $match);
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. This is working. :) Do you have any suggestion to match the new line too? The `m` option is not working.

Comment: @OhhMee Use `s` modifier.